Does an uniform rod hinged at the center rotate when released from any angle?
Considering the gravitational force acts on the CoM of the rod, it should create no torque at all then the rod shouldn't rotate no matter what angle it is released from? Is that correct?

If you’re very careful to release it without giving it any velocity, yes

Of course, assuming the gravitational field is uniform throughout the length of the rod.

It depends on the specific details of the gravitational field and the observers. If the field is perfectly uniform and barring any air resistance (e.g. assuming a vacuum) you can model this by thinking about in terms of it being in a falling elevator.  This is the common thought experiment used to explain the universality of free fall (UFF) within the context of the Equivalence Principle which is still a topic of exploration.
Essentially, without any other force acting, you will not see a rotation.
However, as objects under uniform acceleration approach the speed of light the will encounter certain optical effects (note: this is a link to a youtube video explaining what happens as objects approach the speed of light) depending on their frame of reference. The most significant is the Terrell-Penrose rotation which cause objects to appear rotated by passing observers. This again is not true rotation but an effect caused by the distortion of the optical pathway for objects accelerating to light speed.

The rod will not exhibit rotational motion if it is released without any initial angular velocity about its center of mass.
In the context of a uniform gravitational field, and in the absence of any initial rotational motion, the angular momentum of the rod relative to its center of mass is identically zero.
Given that the torque generated by the rod's weight, when considered about the same point, is also zero and independent on the initial angle, the angular momentum remains conserved and continues to be zero throughout the motion.
